# Firebase Database reference toSON returns numeric keys

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am trying to fetch numbers from a table in my Firebase Database called **/numbers** using the `toJSON()` method of the reference object. This is done with the node.js `admin` object. The keys in the table are in E.164 format, so they are numbers like `+15555555555`. Such is the structure

```
numbers: {
    +18392998683: 'some_user_id',
    +18589392928: 'another_user_id',
    ....
}
```

I am expecting the keys to be the ones I supplied, but instead I receive numeric array subscripts for each entry: 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. when doing

```
for (key in numbersObj)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's impossible to say what you're getting back without seeing how you store the data in the database. So please share the code that *writes* the data. Also: please share a snippet the actual JSON from the database, by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out calling `toJSON()` on the reference does not directly return the object, but instead a representation of the reference, in this case an https link to the reference itself.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#toJSON